# Virtual offices or business centers in Ensenada Mexico?

Tags: mexico, work, working-holiday

I am visiting a friend in Ensenada Mexico but I still need to work remotely. The conditions at their place, and most other places like Starbucks, are not ideal for quiet, focused work. Are there any virtual office spaces in Ensenada - do they even exist there? Or does anyone else have any ideas on how to be able to find a quiet space to work in with a wifi connection?

Comment: @pnuts I have received an offer to stay with my friend and I don't want to offend them by going to a hotel

Answer (score 4):

> The conditions at their place, and most other places like Starbucks, are not ideal for quiet, focused work.

I had to write my thesis while I was abroad and I tried to go to a **bar** first. The situation was ideal until 5pm. They provided wifi and you were able to drink a coffee while working. Then, it was a disaster. It is not possible to concentrate because of the music and the people taking. But, I guess with some research you could find abar that would better fit your needs.

Since the bar was closed during the mornings I would go to a library I found online. Public **Libraries** will give you the necessary quietness to focus on your work and often give you access to WIFI, printers and other stuff you might need.
You can find it online, or once you get to Ensenada, you can either vitit the Tourism office or call them to ask them about the nearest library.

You can check this website that show the libraries around you : http://www.librarytechnology.org

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for would be a co-working space. They are specifically catered towards remote workers/digital nomads and offer an office like environment for working. They do charge however.

You can find many on [CityMaps](https://citymaps.com/r/mexico/estado-de-baja-california/ensenada/c/coworking-space).